# JS regex. How to combine two expressions into one?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How can I use one instead of two replacements here?

```
let example1 = '$138,575,789';
let example2 = '$13g8,575$,7$89рр$';

example1.replace(/^\$/, '').replace(/,/g, ''); //'138575789'
example2.replace(/^\$/, '').replace(/,/g, ''); //'13g8575$7$89рр$'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `|` in your regex:

```
example1.replace(/(^\$)|,/g, '');
example2.replace(/(^\$)|,/g, '')
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

With an OR `|`

```
replace(/(^\$)|,/g, '')
```